# Use of Win32 processes and threads in one Perl module

Tags: multithreading, perl, thread-safety

Perl code which I'm trying to adapt to running on Windows, among other things, needs to start a separate process and to execute some multi-thread flow (the process might either keep running or exit at some point while the multi-thread flow is being executed).

Essentially, the logic is like this:

```
use Win32::Process;
use threads;
use strict;

my $proc;
Win32::Process::Create($proc,'dir','',0,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS(),".");

my $t1= threads->create(\&thread_proc);
my $t2= threads->create(\&thread_proc);

sleep 2;
print "Waiting for thread ".$t1->tid." to exit\n";
$t1->join();
print "Waiting for thread ".$t2->tid." to exit\n";
$t2->join();
print "All done.\n";
# Cleanup would be here

sub thread_proc {
  foreach (1..5) {
    print "Thread ".threads->tid." waiting $_\n";
    sleep 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When execution reaches the 2nd `join`, Perl aborts (debugger claims that heap is corrupted).

If I comment out `Win32::Process::Create` above, it works.

Replacing `Win32::Process` with `Win32::Job` doesn't help, although it additionally produces the message

```
Free to wrong pool 4a47c0 not 328400 at ...
```

Wrapping up the whole thread logic into a `BEGIN {}` block seems to make the crash go away, but it's not a desirable workaround, since in the real code the thread-related logic is more complicated and can't be easily localized.

In [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Process-0.16/Process.pm) or [Win32::Job](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Job-0.05/Job.pm) documentation (or anywhere else) I couldn't find any information about these modules being thread-unsafe.

So, the question is, whether the code is wrong or it's the generic problem with the modules, and in the latter case, is there any analogue which is known to be reasonably crash-safe?

> Strawberry perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for
>   MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Comment: [Just forking](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=regexredux&lang=perl&id=3) might be simpler.

Comment: Agree, I'm leaning towards it. I've been experimenting and it seems to be working so far. It was already so on Linux, but for Windows the implementation was different on some reason, through threads/processes as above. From some googling, it seems that forking on Windows was and still is rather frowned upon, maybe that's why the other approach was chosen. But if it turns out that the "smart" ways really don't work, I'll make it fork universally.

Comment: Now I don't understand the question at all -- why do you have that `Win32::Process::Create` there? I thought you wanted to run threads in a separate process, but if you don't want to mix them (better!) then what are you asking?  Note that fork on Win32 is servicable and there are also good modules for that.  It is much simpler to fork unless you need to exchange data in a complex way.  (Please tag people you are addressing so they get notified)

Comment: @zdim : the _goal_ is to run an executable from inside the Perl in a way that the Perl code would have certain control over it later (e.g. ability to get the pid, to kill, etc.), _and_ to run some concurrent flow from the Perl itself; the _reason_ why `Win32::Process` is there is because it was in the code, it's not my creation; and finally, the _question_ is why the code above crashes, is it essentially wrong, or is the used module not thread-safe and if so, whether it has better analogues. Forking is a known possibility, but it's questionable on Windows, so I'm interested in alternatives

Comment: Ah, why don't you say so :). My comments were conditional on this (phrased as questions). I looked at the docs more carefully ... I'm removing some comments as they are indeed off-mark.

Comment: I removed all but one of my comments, to not distract from the question.

Comment: Okay, I've removed my answers to the deleted comments as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you intend this process you spawn to outlast your Perl program? Do you intend to communicate with the process you spawn?

In most instances, just using plain `fork` (which is emulated on Windows, but things mostly work) is going to be better unless you want to interact with `$proc` in Windows specific ways. Also, keep in mind that normally `dir` is a `cmd.exe` builtin so `Win32::Process` will not be able to run in it unless you have a `dir.exe` or `dir.com` or `dir.bat` or similar on your `%PATH%`.

I can replicate a crash with the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$| = 1;

use v5.24; # why not?
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;

use feature 'signatures';
no warnings 'experimental::signatures';

use autouse Carp => qw( croak );
use Win32::GuiTest qw( FindWindowLike SendKeys SetForegroundWindow );
use Win32::Process;
use Win32;

run();

sub run {
    Win32::Process::Create(
        my $proc,
        'C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe',
        'notepad.exe',
        0,
        +NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        '.',
    ) or croak Win32::FormatMessage(Win32::GetLastError());

    my @thr = map threads->create(\&task), 1 .. 2;

    threads->yield;

    my @windows;
    do {
        @windows = FindWindowLike(0, 'Notepad');
    } until (@windows);

    wait_for_thread($_, $windows[0]) for @thr;

    say 'All done.';

    SetForegroundWindow($windows[0]);
    SendKeys('%fxn');

    $proc->Wait(+INFINITE);
    return;
}

sub task {
    my $tid = threads->tid;
    say "Thread $tid waiting ($_)" for 1 .. 5;
    threads->yield;
    return;
}

sub wait_for_thread($thr, $window) {
    my $msg = sprintf "Waiting for thread %d\n", $thr->tid;
    print $msg;

    SetForegroundWindow($window);
    SendKeys($msg);

    $thr->join;
    return;
}
```

I get this in the debugger:

[image: Visual Studio Debugger]

It is likely that an interaction between `threads` and `Win32::Process` is exposing a bug*.

On the other hand, the following version seems to work fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$| = 1;

use v5.24; # why not?
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;

use feature 'signatures';
no warnings 'experimental::signatures';

use autouse Carp => qw( croak );
use Win32::GuiTest qw( FindWindowLike SendKeys SetForegroundWindow );

run();

sub run {
    defined(my $cpid = fork)
        or croak "Failed to fork: $!";

    if (!$cpid) {
        system 'notepad';
        exit;
    }

    my @thr = map threads->create(\&task), 1 .. 2;

    threads->yield;

    my @windows;
    do {
        @windows = FindWindowLike(0, 'Notepad');
    } until (@windows);

    wait_for_thread($_, $windows[0]) for @thr;

    say 'All done.';

    SetForegroundWindow($windows[0]);
    SendKeys('%fxn');

    1 while waitpid(-1, 0) > 0;
    return;
}

sub task {
    my $tid = threads->tid;
    say "Thread $tid waiting ($_)" for 1 .. 5;
    threads->yield;
    return;
}

sub wait_for_thread($thr, $window) {
    my $msg = sprintf "Waiting for thread %d\n", $thr->tid;
    print $msg;

    SetForegroundWindow($window);
    SendKeys($msg);

    $thr->join;
    return;
}
```

As I mentioned, unless there is a specific reason to use `Win32::Process`, you are probably better off using `fork`.

* Feel free to check with [P5P](https://lists.perl.org/list/perl5-porters.html).

Comment: Thanks. I intend to accept it because (a) it confirms the crash indeed occurs on independent reasons, and (b) I've already switched to `fork`, and it seems to be working so far. I'll wait a bit though to see if there are other ideas. For the questions -- yes, the process _might_ under some circumstances outlast the Perl program, but it can also be restarted during Perl lifetime (which is why I can't use fork _and_ threads, it gets too messy when the process needs to be restarted and threads are already created, but I can use fork everywhere). Communication with the process is minimal.